# Java: Get different entries between two lists Map<String, Object>

Tags: java

I have two lists Map. I want to get different entries between them base on some fields of Object. I've created a method as below:

```
private List<Map<String,Object>> GetDifferentEntries(List<Map<String,Object>> setA, List<Map<String,Object>> setB) {
      List<Map<String,Object>> tmp = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>(setA);
            for(Map<String,Object> a : tmp){
                for(Map<String,Object> b: setB){
                    if(a.get("ID").equals(b.get("ID")) && a.get("ID1").equals(b.get("ID1")) ){
                        setA.remove(a);
                    }
                }        }return setA;}
```

Can I write above method again by using **Stream** class in java 8?

I have an example:

```
 List1={ [ID=1, actor="A", ID1 = 1, film="F"], 
    [ID=2, actor="B", ID1 = 1, film="F"],
    [ID=3, actor="C", ID1 = 1, film="F"]}

List2={ [ID=1, director="A", ID1 = 1, film="F"], 
    [ID=5, director="E", ID1 = 1, film="F"]}

Result = {  [ID=2, actor="B", ID1 = 1, film="F"],
        [ID=3, actor="C", ID1 = 1, film="F"] }
```

Comment: Side note: if you're going to call `remove()` on a list you might want to use an `iterator`. That has two advantages: you don't need to copy the original list (no need for `tmp`) and if `setA` is a linked list removals will be more efficient (and you're using an iterator anyways, for-each just uses it behind the scene).

Comment: @Thomas, but to call `remove()` during using an `Iterator` is not permited. Isn't it ?

Comment: I'd also not iterate over both in nested loops but build some actual set from the first (e.g. by using some wrapper that provides a custom hashCode() and equals() implementation, or provide a custom key and use a map) and then iterate over the second and try to remove any matching element. That would also make it easier to use streams. :)

Comment: @AxelH it you call `remove()` on the iterator itself it is permitted, that's why `Iterator` has a `remove()` method. :)

Comment: Just a side note : `getDifferentEntries` doesn't really mean that you are going to modify the parameter but only create a new `List` containing the difference. Here you are modifying `setA` content.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with Java 8 streams yet but your method could be optimized (as already stated in my comment) and thus be easier to be refactored to streams.

First you should not use nested loops but rather 2 separate loops. Additionally you might want to use a special key object that provides for `ID` and `ID1` as well as appropriate implementations of `hashCode()` and `equals()`. Example:

```
class Key {
  String id;
  String id1;

  int hashCode() { ... }
  boolean equals(Object o) { ... }
}
```

Then build a `LinkedHashMap` for the first list (you could use a `HashMap` but that way you retain the element order):

```
Map<Key, Map<String, Object>> mapA = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for( for(Map<String,Object> a : setA){      
  mapA.put( new Key( a.get("ID"), a.get("ID1") ), a );
}
```

Note that this assumes your lists don't contain duplicates, if they do, you need to do it slightly differently (but I'll leave that to you).

Now that you've got a map for `setA` you can eliminate the elements that are contained in `setB`:

```
for(Map<String,Object> b: setB){
  //if the key is not present nothing will be removed
  mapA.remove( new Key( b.get("ID"), b.get("ID1") ) );
}
```

Finally built a list out of `mapA`:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> prunedSetA = new ArrayList<>( mapA.values() );
```

As you can see, you now have 2 loops and at least the second loop might make use of streams. You could do that for the first loop as well but you might lose the ordering. That's not a problem if order isn't important or you re-sort the list at the end.

Comment: You pass from `m * n` iteration to `m + n` iteration, much better. And the wrapper (key) is more readable

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, I have a question for you.I think the performance is bad if setA and setB are very big. Is there a best way to get result list as fast as possible?

Comment: @Duta the performance would especially bad with your nested loops (O(n * m) complexity) so using 2 loops (and thus having more like O(n+m)) complexity) should be faster. Other than that you'd still need to loop over the elements in both lists to get any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be careful as the method has a side effect on the given parameters. You should NOT modify input parameters (here setA).

Your copy is not deep enough. You created a temporary list. That is ok. But you do not copy the entries as this will cause the side effect of modified input parameters as they come by reference and not by value. The caller cannot trust the input parameters to be the same after he passes them into your method. If you want to avoid the side effect you have also to copy the Maps. Beside that you should only remove elements from the copy.

Next your are only handling the case for the elements that are in SetA. Elements in SetB that are not in SetA ar not recognized. Is this correct?

```
private List<Map<String, Object>> getDifferentEntries(List<Map<String, Object>> setA, List<Map<String, Object>> setB) {

    List<Map<String, Object>> result = makeDeepCopyOf(setA);

    setA.stream().forEach((entryA) -> {

        setB.stream().forEach((entryB) -> {

            if (entryA.get("ID").equals(entryB.get("ID")) && entryA.get("ID1").equals(entryB.get("ID1"))) {
                result.remove(entryA);
            }

        });

    });

    return result;

}
```

To go with parallelism you can use parallel streams. It will load your CPUs without caring about thread handling:

```
setA.stream().parallel().forEach(...

setB.stream().parallel().forEach(...
```

Then you have to extract the statement that removes an element to a synchronized method as this method will be called asynchronously.

```
private synchronized removeElementFrom(List<Map<String, Object>> list, Map<String, Object> entry) {
    list.remove(entry);
}
```

OR you consider to wrap the copy of setA into a suitable synchronized datastructure:

```
     List<Map<String, Object>> result = Collections.synchronizedList(makeDeepCopyOf(setA));
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Sorry, I have a question for you.I think the performance is bad if setA and setB are very big. Is there a best way to get result list as fast as possible?

Comment: You effectively have to compare each element in A with each element in B to determine which element is not present. I am not an expert in calculating algorithm complexitiy but I think it is n^2. The only thing I see to speed up is parallelism. I will extend my answer.